# Fragments disappears after there are another heavy applications started

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have Activity with five fragments which switch by pressing button in `BottomNavigationView`:

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.first:
                replaceFragment(FIRST_TAG);
                return true;
            case R.id.other:
           // last four fragments
            default:
                return false;
        }
    });
```

in replaceFragment:

```
private void replaceFragment(@NonNull String tag) {
    if (!checkFragment(tag)) {
          addFragment(getFragmentByTag(tag), tag);
    }
    showFragment(tag);
}
```

сheckFragment:

```
private boolean checkFragment(String tag) {
    return fm.findFragmentByTag(tag) != null;
}
```

addFragment:

```
private void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    if (!checkFragment(tag)) {
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame, fragment, tag).hide(fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

showFragment:

```
private void showFragment(String tag) {
    // currentFragmentTag defines as FIRST_TAG in fields block
    currentFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(currentFragmentTag);
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    if (currentFragment != null) {
        transaction.hide(currentFragment);
    }
    transaction
            .attach(getFragmentByTag(tag))
            .show(getFragmentByTag(tag))
            .commit();
    currentFragmentTag = tag;
}
```

This was done to avoid load data in fragments every time when fragment is shown! All fragments added to `FragmentManager` only once and later there are only calls **hide(previousFragment)** and **show(nextFragment)**.

This works well! 
Before app goes to background and new heavy app is launched. In background activity of my app is destroyed and when I return to app there is only `BottomNavigationView` and empty display.
I checked in debug. And `FragmentManaget.getActiveFragments()` returns list of five fragments. 
So, Activity is restored, `FragmentManager` is restored, `FragmentManager` contains fragment.
Why fragments not shown on display?

Comment: It is good to use a view pager for caching the fragment. You may use a ViewPager with your BottomNavigationView.

Comment: I would go for the viewpager too but if you want to keep what you have, you can save the fragment in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore it in `onRestoreInstanceState()` (you keep just the id or a simple int like fragment 5)

Answer (score 0):

After skimming through your code what I can think of, is to set one of the five fragments as a default fragment to be displayed when the app runs.
Try something like:

```
bottomNavigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.first).setChecked(true);
```

Do this inside `onCreate()` or `onResume()`;
Good luck!